# Strange? issue with cast of List<T> to array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I've defined List

```
private class Kamery
    {
        public int iIndeks;
        public string strNazwa;

        public Kamery(int Indeks, string Nazwa)
        {
            iIndeks = Indeks;
            strNazwa = Nazwa;
        }
    }
    List<Kamery> lKamery = new List<Kamery>();
```

I'd like to cast searched list of names to string array like:

```
string[] strNazwa = (string)lKamery.Find(item => item.iIndeks == iIndeks).strNazwa.ToArray();
```

But compiler says Cannot convert type 'char[]' to 'string'
Why? How it needs to be done?

Comment: Which language is it?

Comment: `strNazwa` is a string, which is an `IEnumerable<char>`, so `strNazwa.ToArray()` returns an array of char, not a string.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what your desired output is.  Do you an array with each `strNazwa` from the source that matches the condition?  Or do you want an array with the value from the one item that matches the condition?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
string[] strNazwa = lKamery.Where(item => item.iIndeks == iIndeks)
                           .Select(item => item.strNazwa)
                           .ToArray();
```

That will give you a string array that contains each of the `strNazwa` values from the list for items that meet the `Where` condition.

Here's what your original code was doing:

```
string[] strNazwa = (string)
                               // get the one item that matches the condition
                       lKamery.Find(item => item.iIndeks ==Indeks) 
                               // get the strNazwa property from that one item
                              .strNazwa
                               // return the string as a char array
                              .ToArray();
```

When you try to cast the `char[]` to a `string` it fails since you can't *cast* it.  You can *create* a string from a character array but not via a cast.

Comment: Unless OP answers with desired output, this will have to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that .Find returns only 1 value , the first match in the list.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx

This value will be a string and by using .toArray , you are converting that string to a char[ ] and then trying to cast it back to string.

I'm not that good at c# , so the generic solution would be:

Declare the array, do a foreach and every time the id matches put the name into the array and inc the index. This limits it somewhat as you have to have a fixed size, would probably be better to use List instead.